# Can i simplify this creation of an array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I need to create an array like this with numpy in python:

[image: array]

This is my current attempt:

```
array = np.zeros([3, 3])

array[0, 0] = 1
array[0, 1] = 2
array[0, 2] = 3

array[1, 0] = 2
array[1, 1] = 4
array[1, 2] = 6

array[2, 0] = 3
array[2, 1] = 6
array[2, 2] = 9

print(array)
```

Is there a way to simplify this, Im pretty sure there is. However, i dont know how. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

definitely :)  One option that is straightforward:

```
arr = np.arange(1,4)
my_arr = np.vstack((arr, 2*arr, 3*arr))
```

or you can use broadcasting.  [Broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) is powerful and straightforward, but can be confusing if you don't read the documentation. In this case you make a (1x3) array, a (3x1) array, then multiply them and broadcasting is used to generate a (3x3):

```
my_arr = np.arange(1,4) * np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(-1,1)
```

output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create an array full of zeros then assign each element individually, you can pass a list literal to `np.array`:

```
np.array([[1, 2, 3],
          [2, 4, 6],
          [3, 6, 9]])
```